# Moving to Cinnamon from KDE

Tags: kubuntu, kde, cinnamon, plasma

I am running Kumubnu 18.04. Initially, my DE was Plasma but I installed Cinnamon (`apt-get install cinnamon`) to try it out and am impressed.

So, presently, I run a hybrid kind of system. When I start the computer, I am greeted with KDE Login Manager but I work almost exclusively in Cinnamon.

Given that I am almost always using Cinnamon, is it possible/ advisable/ recommended to move to a pure Cinnamon installation?

Also, I would prefer not to reinstall the OS. My `/home` is on the same partition as my `/`. Reinstalling OS will be a lot of hassle.

And if yes, how do I do it?

Comment: People over at the Linux Mint forum usually recommend just the one desktop environment at a time. If you prefer Cinnamon, I'd say move to Linux Mint which is where Cinnamon originated and you'll get the best support there.

Comment: @DKBose Thanks. But I would prefer not to reinstall the OS. My `/home` is on the same partition as my `/`. Reinstalling OS is a lot of hassle. I have edited the question to include this.